# splitting a variable using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a variable with value as "myname(1).docx". I want to split this referring to user input. user will provide input as (%) where % is the varible part like 0-9 or a-Z.
I want to split this variable to two .the op should be "myname" and ".docx" after splitting.(splitting done with "(%)" ). I need to do this using VBA.

Can anyone help on this ?

Thanks,
Ruchika

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming enthusiasts. The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating solution efforts usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will allow you to split the string into two, and reconstruct it using a user input as the (%) variable.

```
Sub namesplit()

    Name = "myname(1).docx"

    myVar = InputBox("Give me some input")

    firsthalf = Left(Name, InStr(Name, "(") - 1)
    lasthalf = Right(Name, Len(Name) + 1 - InStr(Name, "."))

    FullString = firsthalf & "(" & myVar & ")" & lasthalf

End Sub
```